# Why is the mirror modifier creating another mesh below?

Tags: mesh, vertices, mirror

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4ORyREz6Nc&feature=youtu.be

I do not know why this is happening or how to fix it. Any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am attempting to retopologize a character. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I do not at the current moment.

Comment: Can we see a more zoomed out view? Alternatively, can you upload the .blend file for review?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I figured out the issue (I had applied the original modifier and was applying a new one, causing the entire mesh to be mirrored).